# 'à partir de ce moment-là': What grammatical rules are involved here?

Tags: grammaire, démonstratifs, suffixes

I came across a phrase and I don't quite understand what is going on here.

> à partir de ce moment-là

The phrase translates to 'From that moment (on)', but what I don't understand is: why is the 'là' in front of the noun and why does it have an accent. Couldn't you just say 'à partir de ce moment'?

Answer (score 2):

*À partir de ce moment* could either mean *from this moment on* or *from that moment on*, since French *ce* doesn't distinguish between *this* and *that*.

To distinguish them, you use *ci* and *là*; *ce moment-là* means *that moment* and *ce moment-ci* means *this moment* (i.e., *now*). If you just say *ce moment*, it's ambiguous (although much of the time you can figure it out from context).

And the reason that *là* has an accent is that it's a different word from *la* (although it has the same pronunciation). The accent is used to distinguish the two words.

Answer (score 0):

Grammar rules are not the concern,  meaning is what's relevant. but Let's see first the dictionary definition of this word (là) and that of a related one;

> (TLFi) **là**  : Adverbe de lieu (plus rarement de temps) marquant le lieu où se trouve le locuteur ou un lieu plus ou moins éloigné de lui.

> (TLFi) **ci** :  Adverbe et particule dém. servant à indiquer la proximité dans l'espace ou le temps; (gén. joint par un trait d'union au mot qu'il détermine; cf. en outre celui-ci, ceci).

- Il y a trois mois la machine est tombée en panne ; **à partir de ce moment-là** elle n'a jamais bien marché jusqu'à ce que Jean commence à s'en occuper; **à partir de ce moment** elle a retrouvé sont état normal et en raison de cela, **à partir de ce moment-ci** vous n'êtes plus en charge de la machine, c'est Jean qui s'en occupera. (user **LPH**)

You can use as well the adverbial particle "ci", but it has a different meaning: it's more or less equivalent to "à partir de maintenant". "À partir de ce moment" can  can be used to refer to a time in the past or to the present moment. Therefore, as I see it, "là" could be dropped.

The optional nature of "là" is confirmed in the TLFi for the locution "à ce moment-là" (definition: alors, dans l'espace de temps considéré),and that locution  is not very different ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moment)).

- Julien, animé dans ce moment d'une force surhumaine, tordit un des chaînons de la chaîne qui retenait l'échelle. (Stendhal,Rouge et Noir,1830, p.358)
- Nous demeurions en famille à ce moment-là, et nombreux.  (Maupassant, Contes et nouv.,t.2, Mlle Perle, 1886, p.632)
- Si je jette un coup d'œil sur mes souvenirs de cette fin de l'année 1914, j'y retrouve les impressions qui dominaient dans mon esprit à ce moment.  (Joffre, Mém.,t.1, 1914, p.481)

As explained in the [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-l%C3%A0), this adverbial particle reinforces the demonstrative "ce".

I should add that the addition of "là" confers to me a certitude of the identity of the moment involved, the use of simply "à ce moment" not being as definite in that respect; this is possibly due in part to the common use of the locution "en ce moment", which means "now".